# C++ Random in Array - Need to replace numbers 22 and 33 with 0

Tags: c++, arrays, random, replace

I made a 4x4 matrix, where the values are random numbers from 15 to 35:

```
int rand_range(int min, int max) {
return rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) * (max - min + 1) + min; }

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {

int arr2[4][4];

srand(time(NULL));
for(arr[4][4] = 0; arr[4][4] < 4; arr[4][4]++)
{
    int arr[22] = {0};
    for(arr2[4][4] = 0; arr2[4][4] < 4; arr2[4][4]++)
    {
        cout << " " << rand_range(15, 35);
    }
putchar('\n');
}

system("pause");
return 0; }
```

And it's working. But I need to make a change. I want to replace numbers 22 and 33 with 0. So, if the generated random number is 22 for example, it should be printed as 0. How can I do that in this example?
Thank you.

Comment: `for(arr[4][4] = 0; arr[4][4] < 4; arr[4][4]++)` What is this meant to do?

Comment: @NeilKirk It should be `int i = 0` He wants to generate a random matrix.

Comment: Dereferencing `arr2[4][4]` will cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    int number = rand_range(15, 35);
    if(number == 22 || number == 33) number = 0;
    cout << " " << number;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's perfect! I am a beginner in c++, so maybe it's simple, but I couldn't solve it. THANK YOU very much!

Comment: You are still not generating a matrix in-program for further processing, you are just printing one to standard out.

Comment: Ok, but I made it. And thanks to all you guys, it's working. :) thanks.

Comment: @Cartman89: Don't use the code in this post! `for(arr2[4][4] = 0; arr2[4][4] < 4; arr2[4][4]++)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Understood! No worries.

Comment: @AndyG Fixed the for loop. The question was about the if statements though

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not very good for doing what you want. Your loops don't really do what you think they should. Try this instead:

```
srand(time(NULL));
int arr2[4][4];

//fill matrix
for(size_t i=0;i<4;++i)
{
    for(size_t j=0;j<4;++j){
    {
        arr2[i][j] = rand_range{15, 35);
    }
}

//print matrix, 0s if 22 or 33
for(size_t i=0;i<4;++i)
{
    for(size_t j=0;j<4;++j){
    {
        if(arr2[i][j] == 22 || arr2[i][j] == 33)
           cout << 0 << " ";
        else
           cout << arr2[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

When you are saying

```
for(arr[4][4] = 0; arr[4][4] < 4; arr[4][4]++)
```

what you're actually doing is assigning `0` to the array at `[4][4]`, which is out of bounds! Accessing it, incrementing it, comparing against `4` are all undefined behavior!

Finally, your `rand_range` function should probably be:

```
int rand_range(int min, int max) {
   return rand() % (max - min) + min;
}
```

As it's currently written, it will always return `min` because `rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0 )` will be less than 1 (not 0 because of `float` conversion). Use my method.

Comment: OK. This looks better, I can see.
As I said, I am a beginner in c/c++, so this is only as my assignment for school. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure. Read a couple primers on loops in C++ and you should be set to go. Many languages loop in similar ways, so learning how to do it properly here is a good step to knowing the general way to do it in *any* language :-)

Comment: Yes, I know, but this was the only way I made it work. I will aprove my code in following weeks. :) thank you.

Comment: This was my first post, by the way. My first question, and I must admit, I didn't expect so many answers, and such a fast answers. Thank you all guys.

Comment: @Cartman89: StackOverflowers are pretty zealous about programming ;-)

Comment: I can see that. :) Ten mins ago, I became one of you. See you around. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is somehow strange and I find it quite funny that it works, but it does.
Anyway, in order to solve the problem, you only have to put the result of rand_range in a variable and then compare. You have to put in the inner for loop something like:

```
int result = rand_range(15, 35);
if (result == 22 || result == 33)
    cout << " 0";
else
    cout << " " << result;
```

But, like I said, the code looks strange. A cleaner version would be something like:

```
int rand_range(int min, int max) {
return rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) * (max - min + 1) + min; }

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {

srand(time(NULL));
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
    {
        int result = rand_range(15, 35);
        if (result == 22 || result == 33)
            cout << " 0";
        else
            cout << " " << result; 
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

system("pause");
return 0; }
```

Comment: You misspelled `cout` as `count`. Also, This code doesn't actually fill the matrix with anything.

Comment: Not just the code, I am funny too when I need to work with c++. It's not "my arrea", but this is only "must" for school. Thank you for help and explanation.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the spelling error. Related to the matrix, the original program did not fill it either and I removed it completely since it is not actually needed if the task is only to display it.

Comment: @skortzy: Good point about displaying, I agree your solution is likely the best given what OP has told us. However, if it's an assignment, then OP might lose points for not actually filling the matrix.

Comment: @AndyG You are most likely right. If the assignment specifically asks for the creation of the matrix or if the assignment is for some array related lesson, the matrix is needed.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will try to improve myself... and my c++.